# ListView With PAgination in android

Tags: android

I am working with pagination in listview . I have two listview activities .on the first listview i am calling web service to load first 10 items in the second listview .It works fine on the second listview i am calling once again the web service to display rest of the content what the problem is on the first list view if i am calling it calls and store it on the database .when second time called it removed the first 10 items and store new record on the data base . i want all the record to be displayed . Also tell me how to get the remaining data from the web service when scroll down .Please Help me

Comment: You can use pulltorefreshlistview to get more data when you scroll down

Comment: i used pull to refresh .There it is again displaying the first 10 records .

Comment: can you post your code. May be not sure but problem is you are clearing your array list when you call web service

Comment: you are correct but how to get the remaining data from the web service to load on the listview please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Check this code
actualListView.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener<ListView>() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<ListView> refreshView) {
            String label = DateUtils.formatDateTime(
                    getApplicationContext(), System.currentTimeMillis(),
                    DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE
                            | DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL);

            // Update the LastUpdatedLabel
            refreshView.getLoadingLayoutProxy().setLastUpdatedLabel(label);

            // Do work to refresh the list here.
            if (GeneralClass.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext())
                    && GeneralClass.isHaveInternet) {
                // start = start + 10;
                new GetDataTask1(start, end).execute();
                // new GetDataTask().execute();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Internet connection not avilable",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```